# In React Js Signup form when click submit it show some Errors

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

Hello Mates I am currently developing a website and i have created a register and login form in my register form when i enter the registration details and click the submit button it shows an error[image: the error in and jpeg image]

I tried truobleshooting the handleInput function but stiil it is the same i have included the handle input function code below

```
  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValues((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [event.target.name]: [event.target.value],
    }));
  };
```

and this is the registraton form code

SIGNUP FORM

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Validation from "./SignupValidation";

function Signup() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValues((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [event.target.name]: [event.target.value],
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(Validation(values));
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3015/signup", values)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data === "Success") {
            navigate("login");
          } else {
            alert("Invalid username or password");
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="background">
      <div className="admin-signing">
        <h2 className="admin-login-heading">Admin Signup</h2>
        <form action="" className="signup-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className="text-box"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Username"
            name="username"
            onChange={handleInput}
          />
          <span>{errors.username && <p> {errors.username} </p>}</span>
          <input
            className="text-box"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleInput}
          />
          <span>{errors.email && <p> {errors.email} </p>}</span>
          <input
            className="text-box"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleInput}
          />
          <span>{errors.password && <p> {errors.password} </p>}</span>
          <button className="login-btn" type="submit">
            Signup
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

SIGNUP VALIDATION

```
export default function Validation(values){
    let error = {};
    const email_pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/;
    const password_pattern = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})/;

    if(values.username === ""){
        error.username = "Username is required";
    }else if (values.username.length < 3){
        error.username = "Username must be more than 3 characters";
    }else if (values.username.length > 15){
        error.username = "Username must be less than 15 characters";
    }

    if (!email_pattern.test(values.email)){
        error.email = "Email is invalid";
    }else if(values.email === ""){
        error.email = "Email is required";
    }else if(!email_pattern.test(values.email)){
        error.email = "Email is invalid";}

    if(values.password === ""){
        error.password = "Password is required";
    }else if (values.password.length < 6){
        error.password = "Password must be more than 6 characters";
    }else if (values.password.length > 15){
        error.password = "Password must be less than 15 characters";
    }else if(!password_pattern.test(values.password)){
        error.password = "Password must contain at least one uppercase, one lowercase, one number and one special character";
    }
}

// Compare this snippet from Front-End/src/Admin/Signup.js:
```

SERVER.JS

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: " root",
  password: "",
  database: "admin",
});

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const sql =
    "INSERT INTO login (`username`,`email`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
  const values = [req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password];
  db.query(sql, [values], (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json("Error");
    }
    return res.json(data);
  });
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
  const values = [req.body.email, req.body.password];
  db.query(sql, values, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json("Error");
    }
    if (data.length > 0) {
      return res.json("Success");
    } else {
      return res.json("Invalid username or password");
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3015, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3015");
});
```

PLEASE CAN YOU HELP ME TO GET THROUGH THIS

Comment: Looks like you are missing return from Validation function. I guess you need to return the error object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rewrite your validation function with a more clear and understandable way :

```js
const validate = (values) => {
  const errors = {};

  // Validate username
  if (!values.username) {
    errors.username = "Username is required";
  } else if (values.username.length < 3 || values.username.length > 15) {
    errors.username = "Username must be between 3 and 15 characters";
  }

  // Validate email
  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = "Email is required";
  } else if (!isValidEmail(values.email)) {
    errors.email = "Email is invalid";
  }

  // Validate password
  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = "Password is required";
  } else if (values.password.length < 6 || values.password.length > 15) {
    errors.password = "Password must be between 6 and 15 characters";
  } else if (!isValidPassword(values.password)) {
    errors.password = "Password must contain at least one uppercase, one lowercase, one number, and one special character";
  }

  return errors;
};

const isValidEmail = (email) => {
  const emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/;
  return emailPattern.test(email);
};

const isValidPassword = (password) => {
  const passwordPattern = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})/;
  return passwordPattern.test(password);
};

export default validate;
```

Second and most important, you should **return `errors` object** from **validate** function.

Answer (score 0):

***Your Errors state has initial value empty object***

but you in code use errors state before submit form
you can use optional chaining `(?.)`

**Example**

`<span>{errors?.username && <p> {errors.username} </p>}</span>`

**Remember**

> When use Logical AND && and you condition is False Actually Render `0` in DOM

Recomended use ternery Oprator

`{errors?.username ? <span> {errors.username} </span> : null}`

[Read More Oure Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
  const [user,setUser]=useState({
  name:'',
  pass:'',
  email:'',
  })
  const [m,setM]=useState([])
  const naviagte =useNavigate()

  const handle = (e)=>{
   setUser({...user,
   [e.target.name]:e.target.value
    })}

   let valdEmail=/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/

   function val(){
   if(user.name.length<3) {
    setM('your error messg')
    }
   else if(!valdEmail.test(user.email)){
    setM('your error messg')
    }
   else  if(user.pass.length<3){
    setM('your error messg')

     }
   else{
   return true
   }

   }

   function check(){
     if(val()){
      axios.post('APi',{
        name:user.name,
        password:user.pass,
        email:user.email 
     })
     .then(()=>{
         naviagte('#')
     })
     .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
      })
        }
      }


   return (
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input onChange={handle} name='name'type="text" />
            </div>
            <div >
                <div>
                    <label>Password:</label>
                </div>
                <input  onChange={handle} name='pass' type="password" />
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input onChange={handle} name='email'type="email" />
            </div>
            <p>{m}</p>
            <div className="mt-8">
                <button onClick={(()=>check())}">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        
       )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).